# rpy2 convert python object to R object in jupyter lab

Tags: python, r

I'm using rpy2 library to use both R and python in the same notebook in jupyter lab. All is working properly (first I installed R essential and second rpy2 library).

To load library I use

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
```

Before each R code i use

```
%%R
```

To convert R object to python, i use

```
%R -o R_object
```

And to convert python object to R i use

```
%R -i python_object
```

My problem is the last code (to convert from python to R). I have the following mistake I don't understand

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-cc234320b667> in <module>
----> 1 get_ipython().run_line_magic('R', '-i python_object')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line, _stack_depth)
   2315                 kwargs['local_ns'] = sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2316             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2317                 result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2318             return result
   2319 

<C:\Users\steph\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\decorator.py:decorator-gen-131> in R(self, line, cell, local_ns)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    186     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    188 
    189         if callable(arg):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\ipython\rmagic.py in R(self, line, cell, local_ns)
    688                         raise NameError("name '%s' is not defined" % input)
    689                 with localconverter(converter) as cv:
--> 690                     ro.r.assign(input, val)
    691 
    692         tmpd = self.setup_graphics(args)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    176                 v = kwargs.pop(k)
    177                 kwargs[r_k] = v
--> 178         return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    179 
    180 pattern_link = re.compile(r'\\link\{(.+?)\}')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    100 
    101     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 102         new_args = [conversion.py2ri(a) for a in args]
    103         new_kwargs = {}
    104         for k, v in kwargs.items():

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    100 
    101     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 102         new_args = [conversion.py2ri(a) for a in args]
    103         new_kwargs = {}
    104         for k, v in kwargs.items():

~\anaconda3\lib\functools.py in wrapper(*args, **kw)
    838                             '1 positional argument')
    839 
--> 840         return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)
    841 
    842     funcname = getattr(func, '__name__', 'singledispatch function')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\numpy2ri.py in nonnumpy2ri(obj)
    119         # For now, go with the default_converter.
    120         # TODO: the conversion system needs an overhaul badly.
--> 121         return ro.default_converter.py2ri(obj)
    122     else:
    123         # The conversion module was "activated"

~\anaconda3\lib\functools.py in wrapper(*args, **kw)
    838                             '1 positional argument')
    839 
--> 840         return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)
    841 
    842     funcname = getattr(func, '__name__', 'singledispatch function')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\conversion.py in _py2ri(obj)
     58     (ri) objects.
     59     """
---> 60     raise NotImplementedError("Conversion 'py2ri' not defined for objects of type '%s'" % str(type(obj)))
     61 
     62 def _py2ro(obj):

NotImplementedError: Conversion 'py2ri' not defined for objects of type '<class 'tuple'>'
```

Someone have an idea what does it mean?

Thanks you in advance

Stéphane

Answer (score 1):

Actually I did some tests. Because this thing exist one of a largest benefit is that we can create or manipulate objects or data in one language and pass it to the other (to do more operations for example).
Apparently it depends how I create object in python (I'm new in python, I'm better in R).
But now both

```
%R -o R_object
```

and

```
%R -i python_object
```

work well. But i didn't check for several different object (matrix etc...). I think I need to use it more to better understand but basicaly it work :)

Have a nice day

Stéphane

Answer (score 1):

`%R`/`%%R` is documented. Try:

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython

?%%R
```

There is also a section in the rpy2 documentation dedicated to notebooks:

https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.4.x/html/generated_rst/notebooks.html

Comment: Thank you I saw it. Actually you can use %%R to indicate it's in R and %R or %%R to convert object depending if you use one row or several in the cell(otherwise there is an error message)
`UsageError: %%R is a cell magic, but the cell body is empty. Did you mean the line magic %R (single %)?`.